# How does printf() works without argument count being explicitly mentioned

Tags: c, printf

In function with variable number of arguments, the "first argument" is "total number of arguments" being passed. But in `printf()` we never mention argument count. So how does it get to know about the total argument list ? How does `printf()` works ?

Comment: [Perhaps this may help](https://www.eskimo.com/~scs/cclass/int/sx11b.html)

Comment: There's one argument for each format specifier (except for %%) and for each * in a format specifier.

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://www.quora.com/How-is-printf-implemented

Comment: _"In function with variable number of arguments, the "first argument" is "total number of arguments" being passed"_ No, it's not.

Comment: Most of the answers clarify the valid `printf()` syntax and confirm "no argument count" is needed. Yet, if you _really want to know_ **How does `printf()` work…**, the best would be to take a look at source code of some of its implementations, such as [this](http://opensource.apple.com//source/shell_cmds/shell_cmds-187/printf/printf.c), or [this](https://github.com/lattera/glibc/blob/master/stdio-common/printf.c).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's look on `printf` declaration structure:

```
int printf(const char *format, ...)
```

`format` is actually the string that contains the text to be written to `stdout`.

The contained embedded format tags are later replaced by the values specified in subsequent additional arguments, and format is set accordingly as required.

Answer (score 3):

You don't supply an argument count to `printf` - You do supply a format string, however - And that specifies how many arguments `printf`should expect.

Very roughly speaking, the number of `%` signs in the format string is the argument count (although reality is a bit more complicated).

Answer (score 1):

Conversion specifiers in the format string tell `printf` the number and types of arguments it should *expect* - for example, the format string `"there are %d vowels in %s\n"` tells `printf` to expect two arguments in addition to the format string, the first one being type `int` and the second being `char *`.

It's up to you to make sure the arguments match up with the format string.  If you don't pass enough arguments, or the argument types don't match what the format string expects, then the behavior is *undefined* (most likely garbled output or a runtime error).  If you pass *too many* arguments, the additional arguments are evaluated, but otherwise the function will operate normally as long as the format string is satisfied.

**Edit**

[Chapter and verse](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf)

> **7.21.6.1 The `fprintf` function**
> ...
> 2     The `fprintf` function writes output to the stream pointed to by `stream`, under control of the string pointed to by `format` that specifies how subsequent arguments are converted for output. If there are insufficient arguments for the format, the behavior is undefined. If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored. The fprintf function returns when the end of the format string is encountered.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your last sentence misses a *not* somewhere.